# Optional query string specification with "Disallow" in robots.txt

Tags: search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I'm creating a robots.txt file for my website which now has a lot of pages.

I'm disallowing all the pages that I do not require to crawl by so:

```
Disallow: /folder/file.aspx
```

I've quite a lot of pages in my website. And there are some that uses query strings with them.

How can I specify optional existence of query string to disallow the robot from crawling?

I've tried this

```
Disallow: /folder/file.aspx?*
```

This will disallow file.aspx with any query string parameters. But will it disallow file_with_no_query_string.aspx if there's a file which is not expected to have query string parameters and I write

```
 Disallow: /folder/file_with_no_query_string.aspx?*
```

Cutting down short:
Specifying "?*" , will it always want a query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as some of the query strings don't need to be crawled you can simply disallow access to the entire file using

`Disallow: /folder/file.aspx*`

This will disallow crawling both on the file on its own as well as all query strings appended to the end of the file.

Comment: No need for the (non-standard) `*` here.

Answer (score 1):

> `Disallow: /folder/file.aspx`

What you had in the beginning is all that's required - in order to block both `/folder/file.apsx` and `/folder/file.aspx?foo=bar`. If in doubt check it with the `robots.txt` testing tool in Google Search Console.

`robots.txt` is *prefix matching*, so there is never any need to include the wildcard (`*`) at the end of the URL path.

The wildcard char (`*`) is also an extension to the original "standard", so for maximum compatibility it should be avoided anyway.